# How to set default editor in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, gedit, default-programs, editor

None of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235866/set-emacs-nw-as-default-editor), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55022/changing-default-editor) nor [this](https://superuser.com/questions/281617/change-default-text-editor-for-crontab-to-vim) worked in setting my default editor. Haven't tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/323773/44293), I'm afraid it won't work either.

So how do I set the default editor to `emacs` or possibly `emacsclient` in 13.04 through the CLI/terminal?

Double-clicking on a text file still opens up to `gedit`.

I specifically say 13.04 because I had no problem in doing so in 11.04 from which I recently upgraded from.

Comment: To clarify, you want to set your GUI editor to a CLI editor? I think a few people are getting hung up on the CLI element but it's actually the XDG default that you're trying to alter, not $EDITOR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you set default applications..

**Point and click:**

Right click on the text file you want to open, choose Properties and then Open with. You should find Emacs in the Recommanded Software list. Click the Set as default button.

**Using the commandline:**

If you want to set default applications using the terminal, you use to XDG tool.

```
xdg-mime default emacs23.desktop text/plain
```

Then try to open a plain text document.

If you want to set default applications for the current user, edit this file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

To edit global settings by hand, see this file:

```
/usr/share/applications/default.list
```

*Edit: Thanks to Oli how made me aware of XDG in the comments below the question*

Comment: [Explanation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345859/how-to-set-default-editor-in-13-04#comment443202_345965)

Comment: Please let me know if this answered it, or if you still need help with your question. Thanks!

Comment: one drawback I see with this approach is that it'll changes the settings for all other users

Comment: See the updated answer..

Comment: It should be `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`. `defaults` is missing the `s`.

Comment: To me worked: `xdg-mime default org.gnome.gedit.desktop text/plain`

Answer (score 15):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

When it comes up choose your editor.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: nope still the same

Comment: although this does not resolve the OP, it does resolve my issue of changing the default editor used by a `git commit` command.

Comment: use select-editor I think it does the same but doesn't need sudo privileges

Answer (score 2):

I have already asked a similar question about [changing all the associations for Gedit to Sublime Text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115113/change-all-associations-from-gedit-to-another-application) (another GUI editor).

That's essentially where you answer lies except instead of using a .desktop file for Sublime Text, you'll be adding one (if one doesn't exist) for Emacs and then just changing all the associations to that.

Comment: if the answers out there work for me/13.04. I'll then have to ask you/moderator to mark this question "duplicate". Or I will flag it.

Comment: flagged as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings -> Details -> default applications and select Emacs as the default application for files. I did this yesterday and it works fine...

Comment: I had the option of doing that, but I prefer doing it through the CLI because that way I get much more insight on what goes around behind the scene.

Comment: So you don't want a solution that works instead you want to find a harder way to do it? -_-

Comment: @hus787 actually, everything is still done behind the scene, using CLI or GUI. If you want to know, you may need to dirty your hands as Oli is suggesting and edit files at hand.

Comment: Doesn't work in 16.04 anyway...as with so many Ubuntu niceities, they are short lived...